# clean install boot fails ... ended up in BusyBox (initramfs) ... a case for e2fsck

Tags: boot, luks, initramfs

The computer gave me some strange errors like 'device not found' always while booting into Ubuntu, so tried to figure it out and used only the tips from this site to get a fast and secure virtual machine, which I know is possible to start up by a USB stick, well now I stuck here with a highly encrypted VM, it starts LUBUNTU from the stick but not my own Ubuntu 14.04 system which is encrypted on the stick as well ... arrgh.

I remember that the final advice was to boot now and cross fingers… well, here I'm.

Finally I got the USB ready to boot, works fine, now I want my system working again with this USB stick as the keyloader ... but how.

The GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3.9 calls up 2 different entries:

1. LUBUNTU
2. Ubuntu

The syntax for loading the second iso is as follows:

```
setparams 'Run /second.iso (if at (hd0,msdos1) alias /isodevice)'
loopback loop /second.iso linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=second.iso splash -- initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
```

and delivers the

```
error: file not found
error: no such disk
error: you need to load the kernel first.
Press any key to continue ...
```

brings me straight back to the GRUB. ???

How to start this by which reference ???

Managed to enter the BIOS, started with the USB stick into Lubuntu, now when I open a terminal:

```
root@lubuntu:/# sudo blkid -c /dev/null
/dev/loop0: LABEL="Lubuntu 13.10 i386" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="419f80ea-a281-4744-a437-9d542e0e53ea" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="7712339f-809a-49c4-a75f-52268e7db087" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="LubuGrubIsoSwp" UUID="d9e77e76-8fbd-47f6-8b79-25386a6f6f11" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="3d1893f5-6e68-46d0-a957-9a9d74dc5d10" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/zram0: UUID="7f6856c8-6fac-4f11-9516-b84096cd0e1e" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/zram1: UUID="516fdaa9-eaa3-4d73-afcf-18b2a48eeeb7" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Backup" UUID="8042115342114F72" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/mapper/luks-7712339f-809a-49c4-a75f-52268e7db087: UUID="Q0yk3A-tXJO-yC6T-tlyw-0X1E-HQ2Y-2eNfOJ" TYPE="LVM2_member"
```

Furthermore ...

```
root@lubuntu:/# cat /etc/fstab
overlayfs / overlayfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/sdb2 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Please, can someone give me some little advice to start my computer again, either in recovery mode or a complete new installation, if this is possible from here?

Should be possible to re/activate it or not ? But how ?

Do you need some more information?

Managed to download `testdisk`, here comes the selection I got:

```
root@lubuntu:/# testdisk
TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Select a media (use Arrow keys, then press Enter):
>Disk /dev/sda - 60 GB / 55 GiB - KINGSTON SVP200S37A60G
 Disk /dev/sdb - 7759 MB / 7400 MiB - TOSHIBA TransMemory
 Disk /dev/sdc - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - SAMSUNG HD105SI
 Disk /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root - 55 GB / 52 GiB
 Disk /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap_1 - 3871 MB / 3692 MiB
 Disk /dev/mapper/luks-7712339f-809a-49c4-a75f-52268e7db087 - 59 GB / 55 GiB
 Disk /dev/dm-0 - 59 GB / 55 GiB
 Disk /dev/dm-1 - 55 GB / 52 GiB
 Disk /dev/dm-2 - 3871 MB / 3692 MiB
```

Now comes the ultimate information for the programmer cracks here:

```
root@lubuntu:/# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 60.0 GB, 60022480896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7297 cylinders, total 117231408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00061965

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   117229567    58363905    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   117229567    58363904   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 7759 MB, 7759462400 bytes
239 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1022 cylinders, total 15155200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000bec46

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048     3084287     1541120   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2         3084288     3903487      409600   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x012773ec

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63  1953518959   976759448+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-7712339f-809a-49c4-a75f-52268e7db087: 59.8 GB, 59762540544 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7265 cylinders, total 116723712 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-7712339f-809a-49c4-a75f-52268e7db087 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root: 55.9 GB, 55889100800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6794 cylinders, total 109158400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap_1: 3871 MB, 3871342592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 470 cylinders, total 7561216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
root@lubuntu:/#
```

How do I use the command `e2fsck` here? How is the exact syntax with my system?

Hope this gives the needed infos to get the system back on track.

The system gets more complicated, tried a re-installation, now the partition is totally scrambled.

Started from a Live/CD 12.04 and used some commands>

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 60.0 GB, 60022480896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7297 cylinders, total 117231408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b173c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   117229567    58363905    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   117229567    58363904   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-e1947161-3359-45a6-bfe2-5a140d8498fe: 59.8 GB, 59762540544 bytes

255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7265 cylinders, total 116723712 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-e1947161-3359-45a6-bfe2-5a140d8498fe doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: 55.9 GB, 55889100800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6794 cylinders, total 109158400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1: 3871 MB, 3871342592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 470 cylinders, total 7561216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdb: 7759 MB, 7759462400 bytes
239 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1022 cylinders, total 15155200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000bec46

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048     3084287     1541120   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2         3084288     3903487      409600   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

What can I do to get the system back to work?

Got my system back, how, I burned myself a LIVE-CD from openSuse 13.1, started with it, replaced all the Ubuntu mess up with the encrypted  LVM raid, now the system works fine and superfast again, no need to rebuild it, will stay with the openSuse.

Thanks to all for the help, have a nice and good time with Ubuntu, maybe I will give it a try and install it beside openSuse ... makes this sense.

Comment: I started on an older kernel version (using grub) logged in on tty1 and reinstalled `initramfs` using `apt-get`

Comment: Errr, why don't you just use your CD-Rom / DVD-Rom to install ubuntu again? If you cannot boot from external media you have to edit your BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Ok, but how, please.  What do I have to change ?

Comment: 1. go to your BIOS/UEFI: enable boot from external media             2. set bootorder to `1.USB  2.CDROM 3.internal harddisk`

Comment: Okay, if your machine is starting, you see at first `POST`-logo then there will be a message like `<F2> to enter Setup` or `<F12> to enter boot menue` or something like that. Then hit `F2` or whatever

Comment: I do not think, that you can reactivate it. It seems like it is pretty much damaged. get a new Image from ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de (if you are from germany this is the best server.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows); different source of problem, same solution

Comment: Funny so far , the grub has gone, I do have a LIVE CD and a backup on the USB but how to get it start again from here? How can I start it from srd0, so  I am able to have a terminal with all unix commands. the BusyShell is  missing some commands.

Comment: Got once into BIOS have changed the bootorder, rebooted ... Busybox again. Can't re-install from here, does this mean I have to blank out the SSD firsthand or how can I overwrite it with an older kernel and a simple FS, would start with the 12.04 from the CD Ido have as well as I do have the PASSWD for the SSD.

Comment: Hip hip hurraeh ; got the trick to open the "Active Setup Utility" which was captured by Ubuntu; had to press F12  right after power on button. Changed the boot order; so that the system.startsfrom USB; now I try to install Lubuntu 13.10 right beside the old found system ... had the message that there is alrdady a ISO from Ubuntu ... now it installs it beside; has anybidy a glue about how long this might last ... maybe a few hours ... will let it run over night if needed, let's see if the old system.is then recoverable.

Comment: ... arrgh ... doesn't work, seems the SSD is locked by the old system.

Comment: @DavidFoerster : it has defenetly nothing to do with his grub!

Comment: by the way I donot think, that you will need a fsck. I think you will have to rebuild your kernel and initramfs images.

Comment: @JuergenMeixner :you will nee an n entry in your fstab like `UUID=419f80ea-a281-4744-a437-9d542e0e53ea /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1` to mount your `/` partition.

Comment: Thanks, have managed to re-install Ubuntu, have lost all, but what luck the backup is there working fine. :-)

When everything is set up new then I will try to install Lubuntu beside Ubuntu ... let's see what comes up.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have access to the bash shell,try updating the grub to look for devices to mount

```
sudo update-grub
```

This may help in mounting the partition while booting.

Comment: Then try manually mounting the root partition with rw option  `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: Have entered above some more info, could you please give advice how to proceed.

Comment: Try reinstalling it. If it still doesn't work then checkout this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1561735) .  It is a pretty long thread. So you need to have patience. ;-)

Comment: Did you try reinstalling it? Start from scratch.

Comment: Do you mean it does not work even while booting through a bootable device like a CD or a flash drive?

Comment: Ok,now I am in the system again, but can't get it to run as I want, still only a VM, temporary started by USB. Now the Hd0 is still locked by the old system, I can't update the grub, so to say the system is good and secure ... i's still there.

Comment: ... so what is the trick ... will not give up ... either the old system runs again and I re-build it or down-grade it until it runs smooth without errors ... or what ...

Comment: Nice system so far, really nice and absolutely safe.

lubuntu@lubuntu:/$ mount -o remount,rw /


mount: only root can do that

Great, that's funny ... I'm the owner of this machine and can't get root access when I start the machine normally.

Answer (score 0):

**For reinstallation:**

1. boot from CD/USB/DVD as I mentioned above
2. open Terminal & get root :

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

   then enter `sudo su`
3. use GNU parted to delete all partitions

   `parted /dev/sda rm /dev/sda1`

   `parted /dev/sdb rm /dev/sdb1`
    ....
4. hit 2 times <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit the terminal
5. launch the installer gui from the desktop and install your system.

**For repair**

1. start the Bootmedium and get  root access
2. mount the root partition of your system

   `mkdir /mnt`  if /mnt does not exist

   `mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`
3. prepare the chroot

   `mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc`

   `cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf`

   `mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys/`

   `mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev/`
4. Chroot into your system

   `chroot /mnt`
5. Try to fix your system...
   `apt-get -f install`    to reinstall broken things

   `apt-get dist-upgrade`       to rebuild the boot-images

   `apt-get install --reinstall initramfs`

   `update-grub` or `grub-mkconfig`

   and whatever you think will help.
6. hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit the chroot.

Comment: Thank you for the clear programming steps, but the system is that good it has a software lock on the raid ... 

When I try to repair, then there is already the directory /mnt ... and only root can overwrite it, well I don't want to destroy the system, it is recoverable, it is encrytpted with LUKS.

So your repair won't work, the new installation doesn't work, too because of this software lock of the LVM raid. Funny somehow, can't access my own system but thew whole world can see it via the internet connection ... so please what is this.

Comment: Oh, I had a formatting error there. use `mkdir /mnt` only if you have not got the /mnt mountpoint so xou can jump it (edited my answer)  you should ask maybe on ubuntuusers or in the arch GNU/linux community for some help.

Comment: Cool down, the mkdir command works only in root and then it overwrites it, my software programming does not allow this ... the lock is on.

Do you think I'm in the wrong group here to ask this questions, is this already to deep into unix programming?

Comment: No! I did not intend to say you are at the wrong place! Sorry. I wanted to say, that you may search for help there, too, because there are (maybe) people, wich know more about what to do  after the `chroot`. Especially Arch GNU/Linux users know often a lot about repairing systems.